# To prove $\sup B \leq \sup A$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, self-learning, supremum-and-infimum

Assume $A$ and $B$ are non empty and bounded above and satisfy $B \subseteq  A$. Show that $\sup B \leq \sup A$

I am thinking of proving using contradiction, but I am getting nowhere. Someone please give hints

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Every upper bound of $A$ (so also the least) is an upper bound of $B\subseteq A$.

---

**edit** (alternative using contradiction):

If $\sup B>\sup A$ then some $b\in B$ must exist with $b>\sup A$ and consequently $b\notin A$. This contradicts $B\subseteq A$.

Comment: That will prove equal to part, but equality part ...

Comment: Well if $b$ is an upper bound of $B$ then you are allowed to conclude that $\sup B\leq b$. Practicize this for $b=\sup A$.

Comment: So $\sup B \leq b \leq \sup A$

Comment: $b$ can be left out. I only invoked it to make things more clear. Just substitute $b=\sup A$. Then $b$ is an upper bound of $B$.

Comment: So the proof is that we first assume that b is upper bound for B and so supB is less than or equal to b. i don't understand why b is less than or equal to sup A

Comment: The proof is: $B\subseteq A$ implies that $\sup A$ is an upper bound of $B$ (for every $x\in B$ we have $x\in A$ so that $x\leq\sup A$). From this we conclude that $\sup B$ (the *least* upper bound of $B$) must satisfy $\sup B\leq\sup A$. Here $\sup B$ carries the name *least upper bound* of $B$ because it will be less or equal than any other upper bound of $B$. And $\sup A$ is one of them.

Comment: i can't do this simple proof.i am worthless

Comment: Keep courage. You are definitely not worthless.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Contradiction part was easier

Comment: I am still thinking why b must exist

Comment: If not then $b\leq\sup A$ for each $b\in B$ and consequently $\sup B\leq\sup A$ contradicting the hypothese $\sup B>\sup A$.

Answer (score 4):

For all $x\in B$, we have $x\in A$, so $x\le sup A$. That means $sup A$ is a upper bound of $B$. This leads to $sup B\le sup A$.

Comment: You need to switch $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @bgsk: Thank you. I edited.

Answer (score 1):

An upper bound for A is an upper bound for B. In particular, the least upper bound for A is an uppper bound for B.